# Why does overloading polymorphic methods with different upper bounds not compile in Scala

Tags: scala, overloading, type-erasure

Why does the following not compile in Scala:

```
class A
class B

object X {
  def f[Q <: A](q: Q): Q = q
  def f[Q <: B](q: Q): Q = q
}
```

with error message

```
<console>:16: error: method f is defined twice
  conflicting symbols both originated in file '<console>'
         def f[Q <: B](q: Q): Q = q
```

To my understanding, after type erasure, `def f[Q <: A](q: Q): Q` should be replaced with its upper bound: `def f(q: A): Any` and the second overloaded `f` correspondingly. So they should be distinguishable after type erasure.

So why does Scala complain anyway?

Comment: I found this old post about what seems to be the same issues. http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/4625.html

Comment: so, after reading that thread, this means it's "just" a bug in the Scala compiler that will probably never be fixed; but hopefully works in Dotty. Also, if you repost this comment as answer, I'll accept it as correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-posting comment as an answer to improve visibility.

I found this old post about what seems to be the same issue: http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/4625.html

It seems to be a *known issue* with the Scala compiler, having to do more with the fact that it would be difficult to support this feature without breaking other (Scala-only) features and guarantees of the compiler. The post also shows few workarounds.

It would be very interesting if any compiler guru here on SO were able to shed some light on whether Dotty - or should I say [Skala](http://scala-lang.org/blog/2017/04/01/announcing-skala.html)? ;) - will plan on fixing it.

Comment: Skala will support it only if you name the type with more than 20 characters (preferably in Deutsch), so compiler could easily distinguish between the classic and advanced case ;)

Answer (score 5):

Just to complement @chengpohi answer, you can actually implement static dispatching (overloading is a particular case) with type-classes:

```
trait A
trait B

implicit class RichA[Q <: A](q: Q){ def f = q }

implicit class RichB[Q <: B](q: Q){ def f = q }

scala> (new A{}).f
res0: A = $anon$1@39c1fe0b

scala> (new B{}).f
res1: B = $anon$1@20011bf
```

The reason why it doesn't work naturally is only that Scala has to mimic Java's overloading (with its erasure) to keep code compatible with external Java-code and Scala's internal features and guarantees. Overloading in your case (but not always) is basically a static call, so it can be processed in compile-time, but JVM's `invokestatic` does dispatching [in runtime](https://cs.au.dk/~mis/dOvs/jvmspec/ref--34.html) unfortunately:

> Before performing the method invokation, the class and the method identified by  are resolved. See Chapter 9 for a description of how methods are resolved.
>
> invokestatic looks at the descriptor given in , and
>   determines how many arguments the method takes (this may be zero). It
>   pops these arguments off the operand stack. Then it searches the list
>   of static methods defined by the class, locating the method methodname
>   with a descriptor descriptor.

So, regardless that it knows about `Q <: A` restriction - it doesn't know about formal type of `Q` in the runtime, so some cases like that one pointed by @chengpohi seem to not possible to detect or resolve (actually they could do it based on the info from linearization - the only disadvantage is the involvement of runtime-type into dispatching).

---

Haskell, for instance, determines the right method in compile-time (as far as I know), so type-classes are able to compensate for the lack of truly static dispatching by deciding the right method to call in compile-time.

P.S. Note that in Haskell overloading is used for dynamic dispatching (pattern matching) and classes for a static one, so it's basically vise-versa in comparison to Java.

Answer (score 2):

This is not only **Scala** support this,  **Java** not support this too:

```
def f[Q <: A](q: Q): Q = q
def f[Q <: B](q: Q): Q = q
```

It's equal to **Java**:

```
public <Q extend A> Q f(q: Q) { return q;}
public <Q extend B> Q f(q: Q) { return q;}
```

As all we know, **type erasure** will remove type in the runtime, for example, there is a type `C` is the both subtype of `A` and `B`,  in the runtime, it will confuse which `f` should `apply`.

There is a code snippet maybe it's helpful to understand this:

As **Scala** `trait`:

```
trait A
trait B

class C extends A with B
```

so `C` is both **subclass** of `A` and `B`. if when pass it to `f` method, it will cause confusions in **runtime**.

so In **Java** is same, we can use `interface` to state **subclass**. this also will cause confusions in **runtime**. example:

```
interface C {
}
interface D {
}
static class A implements D, C {
}
public <Q extends C> Q f(Q q) {
    return q;
}
public <Q extends D> Q f(Q q) {
    return q;
}
new TestTmp().f(new A()) // Ambiguous call in here.
```

Comment: But the emitted types aren't of type `Object`. They are of type `q: A` and `q: B` respectively, since they have an upper bound.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, I have added a `mixed trait`(interface for **Java**) example for this point, maybe it's helpful

Comment: @FabianSchmitthenner, I have updated my answer for `Java` code snippet. @dk14's answer has explained very clear. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to point out that the above is possible in Java. It behaves as expected for `a` and `b`. I can see the problem with traits in Scala because of multiple mixins, but multiple inheritance of classes is not possible.

```
public class A {}
public class B {}

public class Test {
    public <Q extends A> Q f(Q q) {
        System.out.println("with A");
        return q;
    }

    public <Q extends B> Q f(Q q) {
        System.out.println("with B");
        return q;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final A a = new A() {};
        final B b = new B() {};

        final Test test = new Test();

        test.f(a);
        test.f(b);
    }
}
```